# Why are the brackets not displayed in the formula as desired: C=A·(B)

Tags: luacode, formulas

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=A4, 11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}}}

\begin{luacode*}

function A ( F, L, E, I )
      zz = "\\frac{"..F.." \\num{e3} \\cdot "..L.."^3}{"..E.." \\cdot "..I.." \\num{e4}}"
   tex.sprint ( zz )
end

function B ( xi, a, L )
   local beta, zz
   beta = a / L
      zz = "-\\tfrac{1}{2}\\cdot"..beta.."^2\\cdot"..xi.." + "..beta.."\\cdot"..xi..""
   tex.sprint ( zz )
end

function C ( xi, a, L, F, E, I )
      A = A ( F, L, E, I )
      B = B ( xi, a, L )
      zz = ""..A.." \\cdot \\big( "..B.." \\big)"
   tex.sprint ( zz )
end

\end{luacode*}

% Data
\def\L{8000}
\def\a{6000}
\def\XI{0.5}
\def\Fk{70}
\def\youngsmodu{200000}
\def\I{123}
\def\A{\luadirect{tex.print(A(\Fk ,\L ,\youngsmodu ,\I))}}
\def\B{\luadirect{tex.print(B(\XI ,\a ,\L))}}
\def\C{\luadirect{tex.print(C(\XI ,\a ,\L, \Fk ,\youngsmodu ,\I))}}

\begin{document}
\obeylines
$A=\A \\$ \\
$B=\B \\$ \\
$C=\C \\$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited your question so that the image shows. Please check that I did not mess something up. (It could perhaps be good to add some more text explaining a bit what you do and expect, but maybe it is just me not understanding, so...)

Comment: you get `[\directlua]:17: attempt to concatenate a nil value (global 'B')
stack traceback:
        [\directlua]:17: in function 'C'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\luadirect ... { \luacode@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                                  
l.46 $C=\C
`

Comment: beware `\def` will let you over-write standard latex commands with no warning (`\a` and `\L` here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `B` does not return a Lua value, it just prints a string into tex's input buffer so

```
B = B ( xi, a, L )
```

prints tokens to tex but sets `B` nil so you get

```
[\directlua]:17: attempt to concatenate a nil value (global 'B')
stack traceback:
        [\directlua]:17: in function 'C'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\luadirect ... { \luacode@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                                  
l.46 $C=\C
         \\$
?
```

when you concatenate with `..`

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=A4, 11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}}}

\begin{luacode*}

function A ( F, L, E, I )
      return "\\frac{"..F.." \\num{e3} \\cdot "..L.."^3}{"..E.." \\cdot "..I.." \\num{e4}}"
end

function B ( xi, a, L )
   local beta, zz
   beta = a / L
   return "-\\tfrac{1}{2}\\cdot"..beta.."^2\\cdot"..xi.." + "..beta.."\\cdot"..xi..""
end

function C ( xi, a, L, F, E, I )
      AA = A ( F, L, E, I )
      BB = B ( xi, a, L )
      return ""..AA.." \\cdot \\bigl( "..BB.." \\bigr)"
end

\end{luacode*}

% Data
\def\L{8000}
\def\a{6000}
\def\XI{0.5}
\def\Fk{70}
\def\youngsmodu{200000}
\def\I{123}
\def\A{\luadirect{tex.print(A(\Fk ,\L ,\youngsmodu ,\I))}}
\def\B{\luadirect{tex.print(B(\XI ,\a ,\L))}}
\def\C{\luadirect{tex.print(C(\XI ,\a ,\L, \Fk ,\youngsmodu ,\I))}}

\begin{document}
\obeylines
$A=\A \\$ \\
$B=\B \\$ \\
$C=\C \\$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply!

Comment: @PaulJGD if you get any Lua or Tex error, you should ask about the error message, not about any output you get if you scroll past the error. Output after an error is never intended to be usable

Comment: Okay I will remember that. Thanks for the advice.